# in dart How can you pass an method as a parameter

Tags: dart

First, I am teaching myself Dart and this question pertains to an app that I am building. I have been scripting for years but this is my first programming effort.

I have a weapon class and inside the class is a method. I  won't know the name of the object until I instantiate it but I need to execute the method in another class based on some criteria. is there a way to pass in a method?

I have tried passing as a function and as an int. neither of which work. my version of dart is current.

```
class weapon {
    int get rollDamage {
    //do some stuff
    }
}

class actions {
    getStuff (bool runIt) {
        if (runIt) {
            <need to run the method here>; // how can I do this when I don't know the name of the weapon object before hand
        }
    }
}

main {
    var colt = weapon();
    var fun = actions();

    fun.getStuff(true);
}
```

when I passed it in as an int, the method return an int, I got null because method didn't run. when I did it that way, there were no error. passing it in as a function returned an error. In C##, I think, the concept of a delegate looked like it might work. Thanks in advance!

### edit

the code I wrote is pseudo. it was to trying to show my problem and not expecting to run.

```
var colt = weapon();
```

instantiates the weapons class. it is now call colt. therefore, colt.rollDamage works fine

```
var fun = actions();
```

instantiates the actions class.

I need to be able to call "colt.rollDamage" from within the "fun" object. and it needs to be variable based because I could have

```
var colt = weapon();
var remington = weapon();
var glock = weapon();
var desertEagle = weapon();
//etc.
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking, "when I passed it in as an int, ... passing it as a function ..." What is "it"?  What are you trying to pass, and exactly what code did you try?

Comment: Also, you program should not even be able to run since you need to write "main()" instead of "main".

Comment: updated the question with the answers so that it could be formatted. the new stuff is under the "edit"